# What is the left and right table for joins after the first join in SQL(postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, join

I want to know, what constitutes as the left table and the right table after the first join.

For example:

```
From final_productions fp
             left join things.pc p on fp.production_id = p.id
             left join events.time t on fp.tx_id = t.id
             left join things.car c on c.id = fp.channel_id
             right join events.form f on f.production_id = p.id
             left join events.trigger_alert ta on mc.cue_sheet_id = ta.id
```

I know for the first left join `inner join things.pc p on fp.production_id = p.id` the left table would be the table in the `from statement` which is `final_productions`. But what about the other joins(i.e the joins after the first join statement)? Could someone explain this, please? Thanks

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM) says:

> Parentheses can be used around `JOIN` clauses to control the join order. In the absence of parentheses, JOIN clauses nest left-to-right.

So

```
a LEFT JOIN b RIGHT JOIN c
```

is the same as

```
(a LEFT JOIN b) RIGHT JOIN c
```